# check if sendsynchronousrequest was successful

Tags: iphone, request, nsurlconnection, send, synchronous

i just wanted to know if this is the right way to check if a sendsynchronousrequest was successful:

```
NSData* returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
if(returnData == nil)
{
    //code showing an alertView for example
}
else
{
    //do somthing else
}
```

thanks in advance for your feedback
sean

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass something in for your error:

```
NSData* returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:&error];

if(error != 0)
  // good to go
else
  // error
```

But I could be wrong, just quickly glanced at it.

I did see this post though.. I think he's asking a similar thing:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1647649

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with HTTP, then you might also check the status code.  For example:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];

if ((nil != data) && (200 == [response statusCode])) {
    // Process data
}
```

Comment: Just to add, using XCode 6.2 and iOS 8.2, and an https web service, I'm finding that "sendSynchronousRequest" returns a nil NSHTTPURLResponse on services which return a "401 Unauthorized" response.   But, the 'data' return contains a messy XML structure, containing a 'Access is denied' string.   Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to define an error variable set it nil and use its reference in nsurlconnection such that the error is returned in that reference memory position .Check the memory is nil and if nil success,if it has some valid memory it is error

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];

if (error ==nil ) {
    // Success mechanism
}
else
{
 //Failure Mechanism
}
```